# Why two shared libraries with one's symbol set is another's subset could have the same size

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries

I have two shared libraries A and B.

A is linked from a collection of object files. B is linked from exactlly the same collection of object files plus a few more. Both libraries are stripped if that matters. I naturally assume that B's size should be larger than A but I endup with two libraries with exactlly the same size. How could that happen?

I tried to `nm -D` both libraries and verified that B's symbol set is a superset of A's.

Answer (score 1):

> How could that happen?

The smaller library is filled with zeros to pad to some alignment or otherwise constrained size.